# 2012 Ford Focus idle fluctuation

Tags: ford, focus, idle

My car usually idles at 8 or 9 hundred but sometimes it will go down to 500 and start missing and then shut off if I'm not quick to hit the gas. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Are there any codes present?

Comment: Not sure haven't checked

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: Possibly dirty air filter or MAF sensor? At least in my car when the MAF sensor got dirty it would idle very roughly while being perfectly smooth when moving.

Comment: Which engine does this have?

Comment: It has the 2.0 liter

Comment: Does it only happen on decel or a standing idle? Engine hot or cold? It may just need a throttle service.

Comment: It happens when the engine is warm decel and standing idle